# Java dead code elimination... is this code at risk of being optimized out?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction

So, I'm using an API which is a little unfriendly in certain ways.  Basically, this API creates a resource which can be fetched later.  This resource may or may not still exist when we go to fetch it later.

To fetch the previously created resource, you have to use a result guid like so:

```
String resultKey = "12345";
PersistedResult r = mFactory.getPersistedResult(resultKey);
```

Now, the tricky thing here is that `getPersistedResult` does NOT throw an exception when called with an invalid guid... `PersistedResult` is a lazy loader and will only fail when one of its methods is called (causing the object to load itself).

So, to try and determine whether or not the resource is valid, I'm doing the following:

```
PersistedResult r = null;

if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(resultKey)) {
    try {
       r = mFactory.getPersistedResult(resultKey);
       r.getResultCount(); // Triggers exception if result key was invalid.    
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // handle exception
    }
 }
```

**Is my call to `getResultCount` at risk of being optimized out because I'm not using the value?**

Calling any method on `PersistedResult` goes to an external database, just in case that matters.

Thanks

Comment: would the try-catch be around r.getResultCount only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler can't assume that getResultCount() has no side-effects -- therefore it can't remove the call.

Comment: It is not quite as simple as that.  While it cannot *assume* that, it could in theory *prove* that it has no side-effects.  But the other point is that it is that the side-effects could include throwing exceptions, or anything else that might have an observable effect on the program's results.

Comment: To be pedantic, the original poster here made it clear that getResultCount() does have side effects. So if the compiler were smart enough to do such proofs, it would reach the right conclusion. Put another way, if it's not smart enough to do them, it would be an error for it to make the assumption.

Comment: Vance, Thanks yeah that is what I was assuming, I just wanted to be sure.  Dead code elimination seems like it would be a really dangerous optimization technique because it seems most code would have the possibility of side effects.  I'm really not sure how the JVM/javac determines what has side effects vs what doesn't.

Comment: @Polaris878 "Dead code" is code that is determined to be unreachable by normal means, not code with values that go unused. e.g. `if (false) { /* everything here would be considered dead code */ }`.

Answer (score 3):

No, why would it be? Either `getResultCount` won't be inlined, in which case it's a black box and has to be executed because it can do anything, or it will get inlined, in which case the compiler can see that it could potentially throw an exception, and will perform that action.

The fact that it has a return value doesn't matter. If that was a factor, then any function of any complexity would be at risk of getting optimized out if the caller doesn't check its return value.

Comment: That is what I wasn't sure on... just how greedy is dead code elimination in Java?  There is no checked exceptions on these methods... they are all runtime exceptions.  Again, not sure if that matters?

Answer (score 3):

Optimizations at runtime (or compile time, same) are not allowed to give you different results than it would be when nothing is optimized (apart from runtime or memory savings). If here your exception is not thrown because of optimization, this is definitively another behavior, and thus would be a bug.

(Note than in multithreaded environments this is a bit relaxed when concerning the relations between different threads.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Because optimize cannot change **semantic** of code.